# Authentication and keeping track of users for a cross platform game (Steam+mobile)

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, steam, authentication

I've got a question about authentication/user accounts. I'm building a game using Unity that'll be sold on Desktop (through Steam) and Mobile (Play/App Store).

The game has online multiplayer functionality. I'd like to be able to verify if the clients that connect to the server have actually bought the game and have the option to store data for these profiles (nickname, scores, etc.). Obviously I'll need some sort of account system/database for that, but I'd like to know what the most common approach to this problem is for games that are sold on different platforms.

What I'd like to avoid is having to create my own account system, since then I'd have to deal with password reset functionality, e-mails, GDPR, that kind of thing. Also I'd like for the user to have a seamless experience after buying the game and not having to register yet another account specifically for my game.